# Pads length in Altium footprint wizard

Tags: altium

I've trying to make a footprint for a QFN32 package using Altium compliant footprint wizard. The result looks fine :

[image]

The problem that I have  is that I can extend the length of the pads (thinking about the soldering) , even when I set a bigger value for the **L** in the settings , changing the length in the output  component, doesn't help! :

[image]

SO my question is there a way to do that in Altium or the only way is to it manually ?

thanks in advance !

**UPDATE*** 
after Daniel's answer, I've managed to change the pad lenght from 0.8mm to 2mm ! 
the result :

[image]

Comment: I don't use the wizard, personally. You can change all of the pads at once by selecting them all (either selecting them manually or using the "Find Similar Objects" dialog) and go to the PCB Inspector. You can change the length in the PCB inspector and it will apply the change to all selected objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Start over in the wizard and make a new part (easy)
2. Use careful selection and movement to do what you did for all pads (not hard but not simple)

Are you familiar with the PCB Inspector window? It gives you access to the properties of everything that you currently have selected.

A way to approach this might be:

1. Select all the pads on the left side
2. Edit the x-coordinate for the pads in the Inspector to pull them away from the part center
3. Increase the length of all pads in the Inspector (probably increase by 2x the distance you moved it in step 2, which puts the pad's inside back where it started)
4. Repeat for all the other pad groups.

Note this can be done in four selection steps, if you select what you need and then edit in the Inspector as a group.

Comment: thanks for replying!  I've  tried to first way ( starting the wizard again I've  set a bigger length but it didn't change anything , I'm trying the second way !

Comment: This is a good answer. I would definitely go with the Inspector (as I suggested in my comment) but I failed to mention that you'll have to do one side at a time and use the offset to pull the pad out from under the chip.

Comment: Well, if you do the wizard again, the easiest thing to do would be to use the "M" IPC footprint size. This will increase the pad length slightly without crashing the pad into the ground.